# Laravel - how to surround all previous clauses with where clause on builder ?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.6

In database table I have one row :

```
users
id|email|is_deleted
1|test@test.com|1
```

I have this code :

```
User::where('email', 'test@test.com')
    ->orWhere('email', 'test2@test2.com')
    ->get();
```

and this query is generated :

```
select * from users where email = 'admin@myzone.com' or email = 'asdasdas'
```

with one result. Now I want apply where **is_deleted = 0**

If I do like this :

```
User::where('email', 'test@test.com')
    ->orWhere('email', 'test2@test2.com')
    ->where('is_deleted', 0)
    ->get();
```

Generated query is :

```
select * from "users" where "email" = ? or "email" = ? and "users"."deleted_at" is null
```

So far everything works as expected, this query returns one result, but I want only not deleted users, I can do following :

```
User::where(function($query){
    $query->where('email', 'test@test.com')
        ->orWhere('email', 'test2@test2.com')
})->where('is_deleted', 0)
->get();
```

and this will work, but in my code I already have returned builder :

```
function applyNotDeleted(Builder $builder){
    //here I want to filter only not deleted users, 
    //but this is already triggered on builder $query->where('email', 'test@test.com')->orWhere('email', 'test2@test2.com')

    //currently generated query on builder is select * from users where email = 'admin@myzone.com' or email = 'asdasdas'
    //but at this stage I want to create query which will look like select * from "users" where "email" = ? or "email" = ? and "users"."deleted_at" is null

    //something like this 
    $builderNew = $builderNew->where(function($query){
        $query->applyAllLogicFromCurrentBuilder($builder)
    })
    ->where('is_deleted', 0)
    ->get();
}
```

any idea?

Comment: If you are using soft deletes, eloquent does this by itself, and I think you want to look at / read [scopes documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#query-scopes).

Comment: did you try `$builder->where('is_deleted', 0)->get();` ?

Comment: my question is not about soft deletes, soft delete column is deleted_at, also my question is not about scopes...

Comment: @rkj did you read my post ?

Comment: I don't get the field is_deleted as laravel has it's own scope deleted_at which takes care of everything a deleted item has to be taken care of. Double work also means double change of mistakes. Your questions wouldn't exist if you simply followed the laravel recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would use query scope to just obtain non deleted records

```php
public function scopeNotDeleted(Builder $query): Builder
{
    return $query->where('is_deleted', 0);
}
```

and then use it when fetching records

```php
User::notDeleted()->where(function(Builder $query) {
    $query->where('email', 'test@test.com')->orWhere('email', 'test2@test2.com');
})->get();
```

If you are using `applyAllLogicFromCurrentBuilder` method, you can also extract it to the query scope and just chain it with your call like so:

```php
User::allLogicFromCurrentBuilder()->notDeleted()->where(function(Builder $query) {
    $query->where('email', 'test@test.com')->orWhere('email', 'test2@test2.com');
})->get();
```

You can also keep your `applyNotDeleted` method as is, but without the call to `get()` method - this way you can append any further statements to it if need to. I would probably convert it to a `public static` method so you can call it without instantiating model:

```php
User::applyNotDeleted(User::where(function(Builder $query) use ($email) {
    $query->where('email', 'test@test.com')->orWhere('email', 'test2@test2.com');
}))->get();
```

Personally I would prefer the scope approach as it seems a bit cleaner.

Comment: Did you try it?